# Curl and system proxy

Tags: proxy, curl, socks5

I am currently forwarding all my traffic through a ssh tunnel:

```
ssh -ND 8080 user@remote-machine
```

And have set the system socks5 proxy (in system settings under network section) to `127.0.0.1:8080`. Everything works fine, Google Chrome and other programs are using the socks proxy as supposed to.

The problem comes when I'm trying to use `curl` (either in terminal or using it in `PHP`).
What I get is this:

```
user@laptop:~$ curl -v google.com
* About to connect() to proxy 127.0.0.1 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
> GET HTTP://google.com HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: google.com
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
```

I tried to google around but couldn't find anything relevant. So how do I get curl to work with system proxy (if present)? I would like to be able to setup an alias that would work with both cases (proxy and no proxy) because I will not be always willing to use the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HTTP proxy, use `-x`.

Have a `$HOME/.curlrc` with

```
-x 127.0.0.1:8080
```

or make aliases using `curl -x 127.0.0.1:8080 ...` for proxy use.

For SOCKS proxy, looking at `man curl` says:

> ```
>    --socks5 <host[:port]>
>           Use the specified SOCKS5 proxy - but resolve the host name locally. 
>           If the port number is not specified, it is assumed at port 1080.
>
>           This option overrides any previous use of -x, --proxy, as they are mutually exclusive.
> ```

So, use `curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:8080`, ie. `curl --socks5 $socks_proxy`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make it use one of these automatically:
`ALL_PROXY="socks://127.0.0.1:8080/"`
`all_proxy="socks://127.0.0.1:8080/"`
`socks_proxy="socks://127.0.0.1:8080/"`
? `curl -x $socks_proxy url` doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: My bad, missed you're using socks proxy. See improved answer.